# Return result of concatenating multiple strings

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

I want to create a program that remove every line break with a delimiter, then insert `prefix` before the text, and insert `suffix` after the text, so here is the function :

```
private string replacer(string text,string delimiter,string prefix,string suffix)
    {
        string replaced = text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, delimiter);
        string concat = String.Concat(prefix, delimiter, suffix);
        return replaced;
```

and why does the `prefix` and `suffix` is not inserted on text ?
[image]

Comment: Because you return result.. not concat..

Answer (score 2):

you are returning `replaced`. You should return `concat`

```
private string replacer(string text,string delimiter,string prefix,string suffix)
{
    string replaced = text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, delimiter);
    string concat = String.Concat(prefix, delimiter, suffix);
    return concat ;
```

You can also use `string.Format("{0} {1} {2}",prefix, delimter, suffix);` you need to adjust spacing in between.

As per your question, replaced is not doing anything. it should be as follows:

```
private string replacer(string text,string delimiter,string prefix,string suffix)
{
    string replaced = text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, delimiter);
    string concat = String.Concat(prefix, replaced, suffix);
    return concat ;
```

Here replaced will be a new line. Not sure if you wanna do that or just use a delimeter.

Comment: Also, no need to use `String.Concat` explicitly - a simple `prefix + replaced + suffix` will do the same thing.

Comment: I don't understand the role of replaced variable here.that code just concatenates the prefix suffix,delimiter and ignores the replaced

Answer (score 2):

> remove every line break with a delimiter, then insert prefix before
>   the text, and insert suffix after the text, so here is the functio

Apart from returning incorrect variable, you are **not concatenating the values correctly**. You need:

```
string concat = String.Concat(prefix, replaced, suffix);
                                     //^^^^^^ Here replaced instead of delimeter

//and then:
return concat;
```